# [Plugin: Posts 2 Posts] Changing display order of connections

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization

Can I change the order in which connections are displayed ?

If I create say three connections and then display them at the bottom of my article, I will get them in reverse order. How can I change that ?

I tried to use 'orderby' and 'order' but it has no effect whatsoever :

```
$connected_titles = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'as_title',
'nopaging' => true,
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'DESC',
'suppress_filters' => false,
'connected_from' => get_queried_object_id()
));
```

Comment: Explain connections ?

Comment: This plugin is all about connections between different types of posts. I've got article posts and quote posts. One article contains (is connected to) several quotes. I want to be able to display these connected quotes in any order.

Comment: @Martin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/

Comment: how are you displaying them? You should be able to use the regular query arguments for ordering, like `orderby=post_title` etc. Update your answer with your existing code if you can.

Comment: all right I included my code in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `'order' => 'DESC'` with `'order' => 'ASC'`.

Comment: I haven't thought about that I'm such a nut, anyway thanks scribu (and I spent like an hour creating an array to store the posts in the loop and at the end to display them in reverse order grmlgmrlmg!)