# [Plugin: Posts 2 Posts] Controling the display order of connections

Tags: plugin-posts-to-posts

My question resembles one I asked before:

[[Plugin: Posts 2 Posts] Changing display order of connections](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21011/plugin-posts-2-posts-changing-display-order-of-connections)

But now I want to display the connection in the SAME order I created them ! That is, if I attache quote#1 THEN quote#2 to an article, I want quote#1 to appear before quote#2 regardless of the creation date of these quotes, their alphabetical order or whatever. Don't know if I make myself clear o_O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [development version](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/download/) of the plugin (0.8-alpha), you have a 'p2p_orderby' query var, which you can use with WP_Query, like so:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'connected_to' => get_queried_object_id(),
  'p2p_orderby' => 'my_connection_field'
) );
```

More info on connection fields:

https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Connection-information

Note that this is alpha software and you still have some work to do on your own.

Comment: PS: If you want to make sure that I see the question, either tag it with `plugin-posts-to-posts`, or use the wp.org support forums.